# 123-reg subdomain redirect to secure URL

Tags: dns, subdomain, nameservers

I manage the DNS of a URL through 123-reg. I'm looking to create a subdomain and have it redirect to a specific folder of a secure URL for example https://sub.url.com/folder. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some htaccess on the root folder of your domain.

ie:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(sub.)?url.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ FOLDER [L]
```

Re-reading your question..
if users come on a non secure URL, you can always redirect them first to HTTPS like so

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

then redirect to the subfolder.